# Program Error: "Instruction #4 Failed"

Tags: transfer, error, usdc

I sent usdc from binance to backpack wallet and got Program Error: "Instruction #4 Failed"
https://solscan.io/tx/5zz7YNfumsGU2YUW1PMCeMzFRkweqopYchqE96LEWWgWf8XpxkhYKQHSiwd2SbE99s1a9vJvxXH4EPuYTH6WvCwF

before this i sent from OKEX and sol i received. I did this from okex to others address and was OK too.
Help me with this transaction, please

Comment: after 1+ hours transaction was rejected

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Binance tried to create your associated token account for USDC, but it already existed. Maybe their system didn't realize the account was already created. Likely it'll work if you try again, and if not, you should bring it up with Binance support.